# quote files matched by grep

Tags: grep, rm

grep's man page reads

```
"grep -lZ outputs a zero byte after each file name instead of the usual newline"
```

But in my case there are files in the output that still need quotes. In order for this to work:

```
/usr/bin/grep -rlZ 'Not Found'|xargs -0 rm
```

the `-w` in a filename like `-webkit-stuff.html` should not be interpreted as an option to rm. So I'm currently doing this:

```
/usr/bin/grep -rlZ 'Not Found'|\
xargs -0 -I{} find . -type f -name {} -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

That's not efficient. Is there a grep version that has "a better `-print0`"?

How would you do this?

Comment: I really don't think this is anything to do with quoting - your solution works because `find` prefixes the filenames with the starting-point under which it was found (in this case, `./`) so that names like `-webkit-stuff.html` become `./-webkit-stuff.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
/usr/bin/grep -rlZ 'Not Found' | xargs -0 -r rm --
```

where the `--` stops the utility from interpreting anything afterwards as an option, or,

```
/usr/bin/grep -rlZ 'Not Found' . | xargs -0 -r rm
```

which would cause `grep` to prefix the pathnames of all files with `./`.  The `-r` option to `xargs` makes `xargs` *not* run the command if it gets no input from `grep` (i.e. if no files contained the string).

I would personally probably have used `find` though:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qF 'Not found' {} ';' -delete
```

(which I think does the same thing: recursively deleting files that contains the string `Not found`)